# I'm trying to compile a socket program in DevC++ but everytime I do it I get a lot of linker errors like these:

Tags: c++, c

I have previously run the socket program successfully in Linux but I have to export it to WindowsXP, and I must admit I'm relatively new to programming in WindowsXP. These are the header files I used in the WindowsXP version

```
    
[Linker error] undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
[Linker error] undefined reference to `htons@4'
[Linker error] undefined reference to `inet_pton'
[Linker error] undefined reference to `socket@12'
```

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
//#include <winsock.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")
int main() {
int iResult;
WSADATA wsaData;
// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}
getch();return 0;}
```

I just found those header files in sample socket programs in the internet and I don't know if I really need all of them, and whether I should use winsock.h or winsock2.h. I also learned that to solve these linker problems I need to link the libraries to the program and that's my main problem now. How do I link the libraries in WindowsXP and make the program in DevC++ work? By the way I'm using C programming language. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: You don't seem to be linking with the `Ws2_32` library.

Comment: Also, the code you show doesn't really match up with the error messages... You don't use `inet_pton` or `socket` anywhere in the code?

Comment: Are you using a makefile?

Comment: uh .... you **do** realize that windows xp is obsolete and unsupported ... ? Your best advice would be : uninstall XP and install a modern windows like 10 - writing software for outdated operating systems (although XP never actually stood up to expectations) wont get you anywhere - your code will also be obsolete, never actually used and forgotten at some point.
Also : one does not simply port C/C++ apps between operating systems, you're free to use OSS compilers and whatnot but with windows that will only lead to trouble - you'd be better off installing Visual Studio and use MSVC ... its free

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
Menu - Project - Project Options - Parameters - Linker
click [Add Library or Object] button
and add "your Dev-Cpp directory"/lib/libws2_32.a

Answer (score 0):

you have to add library of `WSAStartup` `htons` `inet_pton` `socket` functions for linking.

some files with `.a`.

press `ctrl + h` -> `Parameters` -> `Add library or object`

browse some where like `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib` and find your object.